# what is the approach to design edge triggered d flip flop?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

i know the circuit. I implement it using verilog and it giving result correct. like when we have to design any digital circuit we draw truth table. Optimize circuit using K-map and then implement. In case of edge trigger Flip flop( i am considering the easiest flip flop i.e. D flip flop) . How we draw its circuit using gates?

[image: Negative Edge trigger D flip flop]

Comment: I don't understand. If you know the circuit and you can implement it in verilog, then what's the question?

Comment: how this respond only to Falling negative edge. The falling negative edge consider as 1 or 0 ?

Comment: An edge is an edge, neither 1 or 0. If it's falling then it's from 1 to 0.

Comment: When clk is in it negative edge then how we determine q? (what is the value of clk that time (0 or 1))

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) can help, especially the part about edge triggered.

Comment: Answer: Your diagram may be correct, but it is not complete.  Something that is required in the operation of an edge-triggered flip-flop, but is only *implicit* in the diagram, is a tightly-controlled propagation delay.  Therefore, you can't make a simple truth-table that describes how this works in terms of combinational logic.   Instead, the truth-table has to call out the before vs. after states. Implementing this in Verilog in terms of @(posedge clock) is cheating as well because that also hides the complexity of the otherwise implicit (but required) propagation delay.

Comment: Another note: I think your diagram is correct in terms of the wiring, but the labeling is *not* correct.  First of all, the component is composed of [NAND-based SR latches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#SR_NAND_latch), which means that the SR inputs are active low.  So what you have labeled as 's' and 'r' should actually be 'sbar' and 'rbar'.  Furthermore, what you have labeled as 's' and 'sbar' will not really be complements of each other (the same goes for 'r' and 'rbar') since the inputs to the input latches  (one being 'clk') sometimes take on "not allowed" values.

Comment: Funny story -- I just stumbled across this diagram in one of my textbooks.  I recognized it because 's' and 'sbar' are backwards, as I noted previously.

Comment: @nobar, the circuit presented uses three S-R latches to achieve a true edge-triggered D FF. It is not critically dependent on any propogation delay, unlike some earlier FF designs. The earliest uses of this circuit which I've found are the SN7474, at least as early as 1967, and the MC3060, at least as early as 1968.